# Mailchimp landing page to be integrated with AWS hosted website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hosting, mailchimp

I have implemented a landing page using mailchimp and it's ready and published under `https://mailchi.mp/maydomain/mylandingpage`

My website is hosted in AWS. I'm new to it and I want to deploy the landing page to be integrated with the website: `https://mydomain/landingpage`

I thought of creating an S3 bucket to host my landing page but as I mentioned, it's already live. Is it possible to create a page that points to another web page?

**Update**

I created an S3 bucket that redirects to the landing page hosted in Mailchimp. What I'm trying to do is to create a sub page (not subdomain) in my website and make it points to the S3 endpoint (if that makes sense)

Comment: The short answer to your question is "Yes, it's possible." The more detailed answer involves "How do you want this to happen?" Do you want to create an alias in Route53 (Amazon's DNS tool) pointing to your s3 bucket? Do you need your landing page in Amazon to interact with MailChimp (look at API Gateway)? Do you need a webpage with javascript that THEN does something with MailChimp (Lambda and API Gateway)? Do you want a developed backend for your landing page (EC2)? We could use a little more info on what your current setup and use-case is...

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan I want to create a sub page (not subdomain) that points to my S3 bucket